# Hash key release in Android for Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to get the hash for the realese application with this code on the Splash class

```
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.myapp", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.i("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

The problem is that getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.myapp", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES) throws an error that can't find the package.

The package name is the same that is in the AndroidManifest.xml

Thank you

Comment: Just a quick suggestion (sorry if not relevant), did you try to get it using "keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
base64" like it says here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: @adiohaion thank you, I tried that, but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the package name I should use is the one defined in build.gradle and not in the AndroidManifest.xml.

I am using Gradle with different flavours, so I used the applicationId for the flavour that is for production.

I hope this is useful for someone else.